# How to call two html file (templates) from one render in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

Is it possible to render one request to two different HTML template? I'm not talking about extending or including HTML file with the help of {% include .html %} or contact block

```
return render(request, "ticketing/all_tasks.html",
                  {'tasks': tasks,
                  'x':x,
                  'y':y,
                   'search_form': search_form})
```

i want x and y in diffrent tamplate and other two in diffrent.

Comment: can you describe more what you need, add the information to your question, but simple answer yes you can use different templates. read this a little https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually, i'm out of town I'll provide my code after few days. but in simple term, i want to render on view request to two different templates at two different location in my project. I'll surely provide code so plz wait for some days thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a parameter in your url and implement a view like

```
def myview(request) :

    type = request.GET.get('type', 'html')

    # do processing
    if type == 'html':
        # return html
    else if type == 'csv':
        # return csv
```

If you access a url like http://yourserver/myview?type=csv it will render the csv part of the view. When the url http://yourserver/myview is accessed it will return the html part of the view.

Comment: thank you for such quick reply but i have to pages with the same type html and i found out that Django is not providing any default functionality to add two templates in single. I will definitely try your solution but it seems that i have to create new URL for that.